# djangoのwebアプリをデプロイする際に、EC2上でcollectstaticを使用とするとエラーになる

Tags: python, django, amazon-ec2, デプロイ

タイトルのとおり、djangoのwebアプリをデプロイする際に、EC2上でcollectstaticを使用とするとSyntaxErrorになります。内容は以下のとおり。

```
hoge@LAPTOP-hoge:~/env1/mybook$ python manage.py collectstatic
  File "manage.py", line 16
    ) from exc
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

manage.py

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
"""Django's command-line utility for administrative tasks."""
import os
import sys


def main():
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mybook.settings')
    try:
        from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
    except ImportError as exc:
        raise ImportError(
            "Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and "
            "available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you "
            "forget to activate a virtual environment?"
        ) from exc
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

ちなみに、開発環境の方ではうまく動作したので、他の記事にもあるとおりpythonのバージョンの問題なのではないかと考えています。本番環境のEC2上で

```
python -v
```

としてpythonのバージョンを確認すると、python2系になっています。
ただ、python3をインストールしたので

```
python3 -v
```

とすればpython3系がインストールされていることが確認できます。

おそらく、manage.pyを扱う際にpython3系の方にパスが通っていないのだと思われますが、どのように対応したら良いのかわかりません。パスの指定は.bashrcなどのファイルで行うのでしょうか？
ご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたら、よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: `python3` で Python 3.x が起動するのであれば、manage.py の1行目 (`#!`行) を `#!/usr/bin/env python3` にしたり、コマンドラインからの起動も `python3 manage.py collectstatic` にする必要がある気がします。

Comment: 諸事情により返信が遅れてしまい申し訳ございません。
解決しました。ありがとうございました！